# Combine rows when the end time of one is the start time of another, if not then as it is in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

Combine rows when the end time of one is the start time of another, if not then as it is in SQL.
For example:

```
DATE_SRNO   start                   End                       Actual_Date
1          2018-08-04 12:22:00.000  2018-08-04 13:22:00.000   2018-08-04
1          2018-08-04 13:22:00.000  2018-08-04 16:46:00.000   2018-08-04
1          2018-08-04 20:17:00.000  2018-08-04 21:16:00.000   2018-08-04
1          2018-08-04 22:12:00.000  2018-08-04 22:28:00.000   2018-08-04
2          2018-08-05 19:08:00.000  2018-08-05 20:00:00.000   2018-08-05
2          2018-08-05 20:00:00.000  2018-08-05 20:52:00.000   2018-08-05
3          2018-08-20 07:27:00.000  2018-08-21 06:00:00.000   2018-08-20
3          2018-08-21 03:36:00.000  2018-08-21 04:36:00.000   2018-08-20
3          2018-08-21 04:36:00.000  2018-08-21 06:00:00.000   2018-08-20
```

Expected output:

```
Sr.No   start                    End                        Actual_Date
1       2018-08-04 12:22:00.000 2018-08-04 16:46:00.000     2018-08-04
1       2018-08-04 20:17:00.000 2018-08-04 21:16:00.000     2018-08-04
1       2018-08-04 22:12:00.000 2018-08-04 22:28:00.000     2018-08-04
2       2018-08-05 19:08:00.000 2018-08-05 20:52:00.000     2018-08-05
3       2018-08-20 07:27:00.000 2018-08-21 06:00:00.000     2018-08-20
3       2018-08-21 03:36:00.000 2018-08-21 06:00:00.000     2018-08-20
```

I have tried below query but exact output is not getting.

```
SELECT
    T1.Malf_start,
    T2.MalfEnd,
    T1.COMPARE_DATE
FROM
    #temp T1
INNER JOIN
    #temp T2
    ON T2.DATE_SRNO = T1.DATE_SRNO
    AND T2.Malf_start = T1.MalfEnd
```

Below is the result I got.

```
start                   End                     Actual_Date
2018-08-04 12:22:00.000 2018-08-04 16:46:00.000 2018-08-04
2018-08-05 19:08:00.000 2018-08-05 20:52:00.000 2018-08-05
2018-08-21 03:36:00.000 2018-08-21 06:00:00.000 2018-08-20
```

Comment: if not then as it is in SQL? what do you mean by this?

Comment: **Please** tell us which database is being used. "SQL" by itself does not tell us enough to choose the correct syntax for your problem. "SQL" does not mean "SQL Server" by the way.

Comment: It's SQL Server 2017

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    t1.malf_start,
    COALESCE(t2.malf_end, t1.malf_end) AS malf_end,
    t1.actual_date
FROM
    test_date t1
LEFT JOIN
    test_date t2
    ON t1.actual_date = t2.actual_date
    AND t1.malf_end = t2.malf_start
LEFT JOIN
    test_date t3
    ON t1.actual_date = t3.actual_date
    AND t1.malf_start = t3.malf_end
WHERE t3.malf_start IS NULL
```

The explanation:

- T1 is the list of all records.
- T2 is the records where the starting date matches an ending date in T1.
- If there's no T2 match, we show the original T1 ending date.
- T3 is to check if any T1 records were used in T2. We don't want to show the records already attached to T1 records.

Comment: I want start date is 2018-08-04 12:22:00.000 and end date is 2018-08-04 16:46:00.000  for first line. As per your query its show start date is 2018-08-04 13:22:00.000  and end date is 2018-08-04 16:46:00.000

Comment: The left and right sides of the LEFT JOIN were swapped. Please check the result.

Comment: My previous comment wasn't very clear. What I mean is that there was an error in the SQL. It has been fixed and the result now matches your requirements

Answer (score 0):

You need to define *all* rows that are combined.  One way to do this assigns a group to the rows and to determine where new groups start.  Then:

- A cumulative sum of the starts to define the group
- Aggregation by group

This looks like:

```
select date_srno,
       min(malfstart), max(malfend)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case prev_malfend = malfstart then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by date_srno order by malfstart) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(t.malfend) over (partition by t.date_srno order by t.mslfstart) as prev_malfend
            from #temp t
           ) t
     ) t
group by date_srno, grp;
```